# Youtube data API user quota usage Android

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I have been using Youtube Data API v3, and as I am aware, API has a limit of 10,000 Units per day.

I am autheticating user using OAuth, and I want to know is there any way to use Logged in user account, so that the APP daily limit is not used.

As there will be thousands of user which will use the system, and I dont want to add multiple Youtube account for using the API.. Is there any way, I can use only one account and still multiple users can use the APP.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: Does your app only access public information or also private to the user of your app ?

Comment: I am not looking for any private information.. I just want to use the oAuth token for using the data api for youtube video search..

Comment: Just to be sure, you want connected people to use their credits to use your app likewise you don't run out of quota ? If so you could make a bunch of requests to make them create their API token and then they use it. Done locally on Android end in a very precise way may be secure even if many users won't put their credentials into your app if it's not open-source and even with that I would say. Otherwise against YouTube ToS I think you could reverse-engineered how YouTube works for the precise you are looking for, it's not so hard to do.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminLoison so much.. I really appreciate your response.. If possible, would you be able to give me some use case, which will show as you explained..

Comment: There is two ideas in my comment I will only explain the second one as the first seems similar and a bit more complicated. The idea is to be able to get some pieces of information you could get in a graphical quota free manner. To do so use your webbrowser "Network monitoring" tab available through Ctrl + Shift + E and make the action, that you wish to automate, once. By filtering each HTML/XHR and looking at each request Response tab you will find the request doing the trick, then right click and do Copy > Copy as cURL (POSIX). And try to understand the important parameters of the request.

Comment: Thanks once again @BenjaminLoison.. I do understand that we can see the network calls from chrome while inspecting, and can use their credentials for search. As youtube gets millions of request and our small number of request might not be detected. However, I will research and check if the reverse enginerring works for me for longer period of time or not.

Lets see if this works, thanks..